# Logarithmic LFO control of frequency

Tags: web-audio-api

If I understand correctly, and it appears this way audibly, connecting an LFO to osc.frequency  with osc.frequency being ex, 440Hz, and setting LFO gain to the same frequency:

The frequency oscillates between 440Hz and 0Hz. That is, the LFO appears to control the frequency linearly.

What I'm looking for is an obvious method, if one exists, to oscillate frequency defined by, for example, the number of octaves. That is, 440Hz should oscillate up +440 and down -220, rather than +440 to -440. Octave up/down instead of frequency up/down.

It doesn't appear that something such as adding a DC component to the oscillator would be an adequate solution. Although the basic requirement of octave up/octave down may be met, the transition curve of a sinusoid would nevertheless be improper.

The most suitable solution that comes to mind is to use an envelope rather than an oscillator for frequency LFO. However I'm keen to know if there's something obvious in the specification that would innately produce this behavior with oscillators.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "detune" AudioParam rather than frequency.

Comment: Oh nuts, all that drama :D. Thanks!